# PivotalTracker and GitHub integration with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, integration, pivotaltracker

I have been looking around for a PivotalTracker to GitHub integration and have found ways to update PT based on changes made to the GitHub (commits, etc). I am trying to go the other direction and update the GitHub Issue Tracker based on changes made to the PT project/epic/story. Specifically I want to close a bug if it has been resolved which can be observed by looking at the updated PT project/epic/story. I would like to code this script in Python 2.7. Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's pretty broad. What, specifically, do you want your script to do? What have you tried? Have you looked at [GitHub's API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and/or any [libraries designed to work with it](https://developer.github.com/libraries/)?

Comment: @Chris I'm not quite sure where to start or what even to look up in GitHub's API. I imagine there will be HTTP post requests involved from PT to GH but I'm not sure what exact data needs to be sent.

Comment: Well a good place to start would be to decide what you want to change on GitHub. Creating an issue? Closing an issue? Managing pull requests? Something else? Then look up that part of the API documentation.